# How to store data returned by Django view in a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, django

I'm getting data by calling a view, i want to store that data in a JavaScript variable. How to do it?

Here's my view:

```
def myView(request):
    .
    .
    dataToReturn  = "abc"
    .
    return render(request, 'a.html', {'data': dataToReturn})
```

Say this is the script:

```
<script>
    var = myData; //I want to store returned data by django view in var myData
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by a jQuery variable?

Comment: JavaScript variable.

Comment: Could you show the code snippet where you are obtaining the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just access it as you would any other Django variable:

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var mydata = "{{data}}";
document.write("Data is: " + mydata);

</script>
```